# Calling Javascript on a form post to update UI via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Input element that submits a form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Download" id="downloadButton" class="btn-download" />
```

I need the button to call a javascript function, and then post the form normally.

How would that be done in jQuery?

Comment: change the input type to button and add onClick="yourFunctionName" and in your function $("form").submit();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#downloadButton').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //call your function here
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

the `preventDefault()` call is important because it stops the submission of the form so you can call your function before the form submit is called at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<form onsubmit="return doSomething();">
</form>

function doSomething() {
    // do something
    return true;
}
```

If in the `doSomething` function you don't like what you're seeing, then return `false` instead of `true`.

**EDIT**

The jQuery equivalent (to satisfy both commenters): remove the `onsubmit` from the HTML and replace with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("form#myFormId").submit(doSomething);
});
```

Comment: He asked it for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffwKK/)

It changes the case of textbox content to to upper case before submitting the form

```
$('#formID').on('submit', function () {

    //var form = $(this),
    //input = form.find('input[type="text"]');
    //input.val(input.val().toUpperCase());
    //alert(input.val());        
    // call your function here!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vPmV/)

Change input type to `type="button"` and use:

```
$('#downloadButton').click(function() {
    //Do any javascript stuff here
    //And here, etc. Then, when ready...
    $('#yourFormID').submit();
});
```

I recommend assigning an ID attribute to your form as it is good practice.

```
<form id="yourFormID" action="" method="POST">
```

Perhaps you have only one form on this page, in that case `$('form').submit()` is fine. But in future (or perhaps even on this page, you haven't said) you may have multiple forms on a page and therefore the ID is necessary to specify the exact form to be submitted.

Note that if you do NOT change the submit button element's `<input type="submit"` to `<input type="button"`, then you must use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the button's default action. Why bother with that? Just change `type="button"` and use less code and less future confusion.

Comment: you dont need to change nothing.!!

Comment: Read my answer. If you DON'T change it, then OP must use e.preventDefault(). Why add unnecessary complication?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you request:
1.- click a button (adding event handler)
2.- call a function
3.- submit form

```
myfunction(){
 //do wathever you want
 $('#formid').submit();
}

$(document).on("click", "#downloadButton", myfunction);
```

you can do also:

```
$(document).on("click", "#downloadButton", function(event){
  $('#formid').submit();
});
```

without having an extra function

but the solution of @Paritosh is the more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

add a submit event on form.

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formObj = $(this);
    var formData = formObj.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: formData
    }).done(function(response){
        console.info(response);
        // update UI here accordingly.
    });
});
```